# shopify collection displaying product info

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am using Shopify to power my eCommerce site and am trying to display the products in each collection. I want to have a section for each different collection. How can I do this using Liquid? This code below will print the right names but I cant get images, price or links to their page.

```
 {% for product in collections.colectionOne.products %}
    {{ product.title }} 
    {{ product.image  }}<!-- this line does not work, nor will it in a img tag as the sorce -->
 {% endfor %}

 {% for product in collections.colectionTwo.products %}
    {{ product.title }}   
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for product in collections.supa-zxhibt.products %}
    {{ product.title }} 
    <a href="{{product.url}}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}" /></a>
    {{ product.price | money  }} 
{% endfor %}
```